# C# Regex URL Port username & password

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, url

I have a URL and need to extract the port, username and password from it and put them into an array. It looks like following.

`http://myproject.ddns.net:8080/get.php?username=9zu7T54rt6&password=1Tbliu49iH&type=m3u_plus&output=ts`

Can I use some other method without replaces or substring?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: If you've tried something already, please post your code in your question.  If you have not tried anything yet, please give something a try and then come back to us with specific issues you are stuck on.

Comment: @Adrian: It's not a duplicate. OP is asking to extract data from URL not match if it's valid.

Comment: Which only requires making the non-capturing groups capturing groups instead.

Comment: IMO, you should use some scripting language to accomplish this, as simply regex will only go so far. [Here](http://rubular.com/r/AiZq37XXkw) is a very rough attempt.

Comment: This is already built into the `Uri` class; investigate `new Uri(yourUri).Port`, and `Uri.GetComponents()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways in C#

Get the query parameter

```
var parsedQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("http://myproject.ddns.net:8080/get.php?username=9zu7T54rt6&password=1Tbliu49iH&type=m3u_plus&output=ts");
```

Then, below will give the username

```
parsedQuery["username"]
```

For Password:

```
parsedQuery["password"]
```

---

For port you can use `URI` :

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myproject.ddns.net:8080/get.php?username=9zu7T54rt6&password=1Tbliu49iH&type=m3u_plus&output=ts");
```

Get the port by

```
uri.Port
```

Create an array or use whatever you require to club.

Comment: that looks good but i think you need internet connection for it (i know i didn't telled this in my post) but we need to be able to add links to a list even when we are offline. The links we input are "100%" valid but i really like your method and will keep it in mind for my next project :)

Comment: But why u need an internet connection for this? can you explain ?

Comment: i am sorry i thought that will also check if it's available

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, but here's one that works for Python. It's pretty straightforward so you should be able to convert.

```
:(?P<port>[0-9]+).*username=(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*password=(?P<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

The (?P<foo>bar) syntax is a named capture group that will put a variable matching the pattern 'bar' into a variable called 'foo' when you extract them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution with pure C# regex:

```
var url = "http://myproject.ddns.net:8080/get.php?username=9zu7T54rt6&password=1Tbliu49iH&type=m3u_plus&output=ts";
var urlRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=(http(s)?://)?\w+(\.\w+)*:)\d+(?=/.*)?");
var usernameRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=(\?|&)username=).*?(?=&|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var passwordRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=(\?|&)password=).*?(?=&|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(urlRegex.Match(url));
Console.WriteLine(usernameRegex.Match(url));
Console.WriteLine(passwordRegex.Match(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are any parts that don't change, e.g. if it's always the same url you could just replace it like this

```
string str = "http://myproject.ddns.net:8080/get.php?username=9zu7T54rt6&password=1Tbliu49iH&type=m3u_plus&output=ts"
str.Replace("http://myproject.ddns.net","");
```

This would leave you ":8080/get.php?username=9zu7T54rt6&password=1Tbliu49iH&type=m3u_plus&output=ts"

There is nothing stopping you repeating the process with another section.

As for regex you could use Regex.Match https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx to get the parts you want.

You could use **":\d{4}/"** to get the port - you'd have to strip the leading ":" and trailing "/" though; this **"username=\w*\&"** to get the username - you'd have to strip the leading "username=" and trailing "&" though; and for the password you could use **"password=\w*\&"** - you'd have to strip the leading "password=" and trailing "&" though.

If you'd like to experiment with regex this site https://regex101.com/ is pretty good.

Comment: thats how i've done it before ^^ but looks very dirty for me